# Joining three tables using MySQL with foreign Key

Tags: mysql

Right now i have a below query to run only two tables!
But, i would like to joining three tables using MySQL with foreign Key! I paste the SQL code in below to see the foreign key!

```
$sql  = "SELECT student.*, courses.* 
        FROM student 
        INNER JOIN courses ON student.id=courses.id_courses  
        INNER JOIN schedule ON schedule.id_schedule = schedule.id";
```

Here is my DB:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `courses`
--


--
-- Constraints for table `schedule`
--
ALTER TABLE `schedule`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `schedule_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_courses`) REFERENCES `courses` (`id_courses`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `schedule_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `student` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: You're already joining 3 tables.

Comment: You're already joining student, courses, and schedule. What else do you want to join?

Comment: @TheImpaler It does not fetch or show anything! 
It's only works on the:
SELECT student.*, courses.* FROM student INNER JOIN courses ON student.id=courses.id_courses

Comment: Don't use an integer type for phone numbers. They're not really numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're joining 3 tables, but not joining on the correct foreign keys.

```
SELECT student.*, courses.*
FROM schedule
JOIN student ON student.id = schedule.id
JOIN courses ON courses.id_courses = schedule.id_courses
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/m1WDNAC9wCGbD4kHhxTArK/0)

Comment: Thaks, But the code you sending does not run! or fetch anything!

Comment: I had a typo, I just fixed it. Didn't you get an error because of that? Do you check for errors?

Comment: If you're not getting any results, the problem is with the data.

Comment: BUT, I would like to have `schedule_year`, `schedule_semester` from `schedule' table too!

Comment: I'm getting this error:
PHP Warning:  mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/html/01/config.php on line 20

Comment: I'm getting that error after running this query:


SELECT student.*, courses.*, schedule.*
FROM schedule
JOIN student ON student.id = schedule.id
JOIN courses ON courses.id_courses = schedule.id_courses

Comment: The error seems coming from:

 function runQuery($query) {
  $res = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
   $resset[] = $row;
  }  
  if(!empty($resset))
   return $resset;
 }

Comment: Thanks Everyone! 
I was able to find the problem. I should not use "order by"

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `ORDER BY`. You must have been using it wrong. `echo mysqli_error($this->conn);` will tell you what you did wrong.